# Do USB 3.0 male-to-male A-to-A cables swap SSTX and SSRX?

Tags: usb, connector, wiring, cables, standard

There are many USB 3.0 Type A male-to-male cables on the market ([example on Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/LINDY-USB-3-0-Cable-Pro-x/dp/B002WS8D6G)), but I can't find any information on whether they would switch the SSTX and SSRX lines, so that the SSTX pins on one side reach the SSRX pins on the other side and vice versa, or if they connect SSTX to SSTX and SSRX to SSRX instead.

I know that A-to-B cables have opposing pinouts for SSTX and SSRX, so I suspect that in that case the SSTX pins on the A site go to the SSRX pins on the B side, but I'm not sure whether this maps to A-to-A cables.

Is there a standard for this? How are they wired?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cable is specified in section 5.5.2 of the USB 3.0 specification, which is available from [USB.org](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/documents_archive/). I've included a screenshot below, but the short version is:

- VBUS and the USB2 signals (D+ and D-) are *not* connected.
- The TX and RX lines are crossed in each pair.

Note that this is a special-purpose cable. (The standard suggests "operating system debugging" as an example application.) It cannot be used to connect normal devices.

[image]

Comment: Excellent. Interesting that VBUS isn't connected.

Comment: @Polynomial - Not interesting, necessary to prevent killing a system. Note that the cable is intended for host-to-host connection. Since each host will provide VBUS, and at slightly different voltages, a VBUS connection would connect both host VBUS lines together, and the results would not be remotely pleasant.

Comment: Oh, wow, yeah, I never even considered that. That *would* make a mess.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

I buzzed through a [Pro-Signal PSG91171](http://cpc.farnell.com/pro-signal/psg91171/lead-usb3-0-a-male-a-male-2m-white/dp/CS28254):

```
End 1 pin#  End 1 pin label             End 2 pin#  End 2 pin label
1           Vbus            ----------  1           Vbus
2           D-              ----------  2           D-
3           D+              ----------  3           D+
4           GND             ----------  4           GND
5           RX-             ----------  8           TX-
6           RX+             ----------  9           TX+
7           GND             ----------  7           GND
8           TX-             ----------  5           RX-
9           TX+             ----------  6           RX+
Shell       Shield          ----------  Shell       Shield
```

Another [Pro-Signal CAC250018](http://cpc.farnell.com/pro-signal/cac250018/lead-usb3-0-a-male-a-male-1m-blue/dp/CS19537) was the same.

Comment: Oops, I should have looked at the data sheet which has the pinout!